# .NET DataGridView displays 1899-12-30 as part of a time-only value

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, datetimepicker

I set my datetimepicker's value to 1:00 PM or any random hh:mm tt format and insert it into my MSAccess database in a my table with a date/time field. But when my datagridview shows the table, a random "12/30/1899" (+ my input of 1:00 PM). Any idea why this is happening? My code is not here though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access `Date/Time` fields always store both a Date and a Time component. If only a Time value is specified then the Date part defaults to 1899-12-30.

If you want to display just the Time part in a DataGridView column you can set its format to "short time" using something like this (C#, but VB.NET would be very similar):

```csharp
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t";  // short time
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You can bet many are having the same prob on other forums.

Answer (score 0):

it could have been better if you also included your code......

just visit the following link for Date Time Picker information.

[DateTimePicker MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

In visual basic this code works best

dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm"

Where HH:mm is 24 hour format

I had exactly the same issue and inserted that code just before table fill statement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).